# How to address an assembly in xaml, which is located somewhere else

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need help with dynamically loading things in wpf.
The assembly is somewhere under `C:\..\...` etc and I need to address it inside a xaml file.

Take a look at this: pack://application:,,,`C:\..\..\myassembly.dll`;component\Themes\Generic.xaml

I want to get generic.xaml from the assembly located at `C:\..\..\myassembly.dll`
Any way to do this in wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly customise the loading of assemblies using the following code in the startup of your application...

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(LoadFromSomeFolder);

...

private Assembly LoadFromSomeFolder(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\..\..." + args.Name);
}
```

The AssemblyResolve event is only fired when the system fails to resolve the location of an assembly referenced by the application.

Comment: Any specific reason why? The ResolveEventHandler doesn't fire?  An error  is thrown in your app before you can assign the AssemblyResolve event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing an external ResourceDictionary (XAML File):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Referencing an external ResourceDictionary (DLL):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyExternalAssembly;component/MyResources.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Another thing you can do is dynamically import the ResourceDictionary using MEF-Managed Extensibility Framework.

In each assembly with resources, you export the ResourceDictionary object by going code behind and annotating like this:

```
[Export(typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public partial class Resources : ResourceDictionary
{
    public Resources()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now you need a component (your main application) that resolves the import for you.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName("Your destination on C:");

        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection);
        _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);

        var resourceDictionaries = _container.GetExports<ResourceDictionary>();

        foreach (var resourceDictionary in resourceDictionaries)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the exact same issue with my project. This is how I solved it:

Here is the basic resolver class:

```
public sealed class AssemblyResolveHandler
{
    const string LIBRARY_PATH = @"C:\...\...\";

    public static Assembly ResolveEventHandler(object sender, System.ResolveEventArgs e)
    {
        Assembly a = null;
        string assemblyName = e.Name.Substring(0, e.Name.IndexOf(","));

        //Look for the DLL assembly
        a = FindAssembly(LIBRARY_PATH, assemblyName + ".dll");

        if (a == null)
        {   //If no DLL assembly was found, look for an EXE assembly.
            a = FindAssembly(eofSharedFolder, assemblyName + ".exe");
        }

        return a;
    }


    public static Assembly FindAssembly(string appFolder, string fileName, out string logReturn)
    {
        Assembly rtnAssembly = null;
        string targetFolder = appFolder;

        //some dll's are hidden in x64 folders or x86 folders
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            targetFolder += "\x64";
        else
            targetFolder += "\x86";


        string fullCurrentLocation = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + fileName;
        string fullAppLocation = Path.GetFullPath(appFolder) + @"\" + fileName;
        string fullAltLocation = Path.GetFullPath(targetFolder) + @"\" + fileName;

        //make sure it's not in the current folder
        if (File.Exists(fullCurrentLocation))
        {
            rtnAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullCurrentLocation);
        }

        else if (File.Exists(fullAppLocation))
        {
            rtnAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullAppLocation);

        }
        else if (File.Exists(fullAltLocation))
        {
            rtnAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullAltLocation);
        }

        return rtnAssembly;

    }
}
```

Then you call this in your WPF application by going into the App.xaml.cs and adding a constructor override:

```
   public App():base()
    {
        //*****This is used to tell the application how to load DLLs
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(AssemblyResolveHandler.ResolveEventHandler);
    }
```

Making this call in the constructor is the only way to get it to work. WPF generates the function "app.main()" that gets called before "app.OnStartup()" and will always break this assembly resolving code, but a constructor will get called before the generated "main"